# Button accesible from lock screen in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I want to develop an iOS app that can have like a panic button when the screen is locked. This button can be enable or disabled within the app, but 
I want to know if it is possible to add a very accessible button you can press in case of an emergency even when the screen is locked. When the button is pressed I want to execute some code in the app.

Is there a possible way of accomplishing this in iOS?

Or is there an alternative?, The only think that I required is that the button can be pressed like in maximum three seconds even if the screen is locked and the app closed.

Comment: closest you could get is putting up a local notification with an action button, but the user will be able to swipe it away, otherwise you could make a widget for the notification center, but thats not quite on the lock screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that is not possible in iOS. You cannot make changes outside of your app.

One suggestion i can give you is to make a extension for today view in notification center. And you can ask the users to touch the button in notification center to invoke your functionality.

Notification center can be accessed in lock screen also.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into that